# Mobile to mobile "communication" - Xamarin, C#

Tags: mobile, xamarin

I am looking for a pattern/technical solution to the following problem.
I want to have two types of mobile apps, call them Client and Admin. Client would allow one to enter their "client number" or scan a bar code. Upon submission, the following would happen:
1) REST call to a cloud server app which would record the client signing in (got it covered);
2) REST response to the Client app identifying a successful sign-in (got it covered);
3) Call to Admin app identifying a sign-in (successful or not) with client's details (unknown).

I am not sure how to accomplish #3 as it would be the cloud server app pushing information to the Admin app. There could be multiple Client apps and more then one Admin app. Details of all client interactions would have to be pushed to all Admin apps.

I am looking for suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are looking for push notifications. There is a lot of information available regarding push notifications for Xamarin. Here is a good starting point: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/

Comment: Push Notifications is a good solution, if you want to go even further you can have a look at SignalR